# Macos high sierra docker-compose.yml and .env

Tags: docker, docker-compose, macos-high-sierra

While I upgrade to Macos high sierra, the "docker-compose -up -d" and "docker-compose -down" comes not work, get following ERROR from the zsh terminal：

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
:3306", should be [[remote_ip:]remote_port[-remote_port]:]port[/protocol]
:6379", should be [[remote_ip:]remote_port[-remote_port]:]port[/protocol]
```

But it can comes up by the Docker APP from the MacOS stock banner while stop the Docker client and restart.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
8142df6b34b8        redis:alpine        "redis-server --appe…"   13 days ago         Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp   redis
b175d381b6e9        mysql:latest        "/entrypoint.sh --de…"   13 days ago         Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   mysql1000
```

it worked well before i sure, the docker-compose.yml looks like here:

```
ports:
  - ${REDIS_PORT}:6379
```

and the ./.env likes:

```
# REDIS
REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_IP=172.18.0.3
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Anyone knows what's the problem from me? THANKS A LOT!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I find back all the containers and database, after remove all the `${*}` from the docker-compose.yml instead of its real name.

And then uninstall the lovely kitty Kitematic APP...